# PyCharm ошибка в установке PyAudio

Tags: python, pycharm, модули, pyaudio

```
(venv) C:\Users\Maksvel\Downloads>pkg install wget
'pkg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(venv) C:\Users\Maksvel\Downloads>pip install wget
Collecting wget
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/6a/62e288da7bcda82b935ff0c6cfe542970f04e29c756b0e147251b2fb251f/wget-3.2.zip
Installing collected packages: wget
  Running setup.py install for wget ... done
Successfully installed wget-3.2

(venv) C:\Users\Maksvel\Downloads>pip install Pyaudio
Collecting Pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: Pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for Pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Maksvel\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Maksvel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h0wk56o6\\Pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__fi
le__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Maksvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6gpw2ls_\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Maksvel\P
ycharmProjects\untitled\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pyaudio:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Users\Maksvel\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\include -IC:\Users\Maksvel\AppData\Local\Programs\Py
thon\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Maksvel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\To
ols\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windo
ws Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
ols\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windo
ws Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Fil
es (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj    _portaudiomodule.c
    C:\Users\Maksvel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: MS_WIN64: ????????? ????????????????
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: ??. ?????????? ??????????? "MS_WIN64"
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ?? ??????? ??????? ???? ?????????: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
***Command "C:\Users\Maksvel\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Maksvel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h0wk56o6\\Pyaudio\\s
etup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Maksvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip
-record-6gpw2ls_\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Maksvel\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pyaudio" failed with err
or code 1 in C:\Users\Maksvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h0wk56o6\Pyaudio\
```

Не совсем понимаю,в чем ошибка установки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Пользуйтесь встроенным установщиком.*

1. Зайдите в **File - Settings - Projects Interpreter**
2. Справа вверху у списка библиотек нажмите "**+**"
3. В поисковой строке сверху наберите название библиотеки.
4. Выберете в результатах поиска нужную, нажмите кнопку "**Install**"
5. Дождитесь окончания установки, пользуйтесь.

[image: Pycharm установка библиотеки]

Comment: Ошибка осталась ( Не помогло (

Comment: @ЮрийБатяев та же библиотека?